# How can I split a string on characters in Visual C++?

Tags: string, visual-c++

I have been trying to create a Visual C++ program which takes a string from a text box, then counts the number of characters in it and puts each character in different label. With which functions can I take the string from the text box, split the string on characters and put every character in different label?

Comment: please show sample input; desired output, and your current best attempt.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `GetDlgItemText` to copy text into char-array or a `CString` object. If text-control is mapped to a `CEdit` variable, use `GetWindowText` to copy text into buffer.
- Use `strlen` or `CString::GetLength` to find the length of string. If you want to trim spaces, use `CString::Trim`
- Then run a loop starting from 0th index till the length-1. Locate what those characters are, and place them into target controls.